# Inheritance and Instantiating problem using ASP.Net Core 2.1 vs ASP.Net 4.1 MVC in Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Both classes are in a different class file but in the same folder. This is my code.

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Zodiac : Person
{
   public Zodiac()
   {
      //person.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
      DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;// this doesn't work either
   }
      //Person person = new Person();
 }
```

Even I use the Instantiation, it doesn't work even if they are in the same folder. Its giving me this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'DateOfBirth' does not exist in the current
>   context   PersonExercise  D:\Exercises\PersonExercise\PersonExercise\Models\Zodiac.cs 12  Active

If I use the Instantiation, its giving me this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'Person' does not contain a definition for 'DateOfBirth'
>   and no accessible extension method 'DateOfBirth' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Person' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   PersonExercise  D:\Exercises\PersonExercise\PersonExercise\Models\Zodiac.cs 12  Active

Here are the screenshots about the problem:

[Using Inheritance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajcJ3.jpg)

[Using Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhugd.jpg)

Comment: What error are you getting..? Apart from "Datetime" being wrong as it should be `DateTime`.

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with inheritance. Inheritance is a feature of the language. *Folders* have nothing to do with inheritance either. What is the problem? What did you try? What isn't working?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the Problem. But Its giving me a does not contain error or does not exist.

Comment: First, you have a typo. Second, there's no error once the typo is fixed.

Comment: Check my answer, I tell you what both errors mean. @PanagiotisKanavos there  is and additional problem, he has tried to access the parent class property via  person.PropertyName.

Comment: @RandolfS. I'll repeat it. There's no error once the typo is fixed. Post the *actual* code you used both for the classes and for instantiation, including namespaces. You can't instantiate an object at the field level for example. What you provided here can't be used to reproduce the problem

Comment: @bradbury9 in the comments, not the actual code. I copied the code as-is in Linqpad, fixed the typo and run it without problem. `new Zodiac().Dump();` printed out all fields and the current date as expected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, there is a typo, but there is another problem, he tried to `person.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;` which point to not understanding completly inheritance.

Comment: There was not a flag for 'just a typo'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179463/discussion-between-bradbury9-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Please view the image I've attached. Using Inheritance or using instance. Either way. I won't work in a ASP.Net Core 2.1 project in the same Model folder.

Comment: @RandolfS. in the images the property DateOfBirth appears in the Person**s** class. Either you used the wrong base class or you misspelled the class's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some typo + not understanding completly inheritance. Check the comments in the following code.

```
public class Zodiac : Person
{
    public Zodiac()
    {
      person.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now; // This would not work, you have not declared an object named "person", note it is commented.
      DateOfBirth = Datetime.Now;// this doesn't work. <-- Indeed, there is a typo
      DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;// this would work, note the uppercase Time.
    }
    //Person person = new Person();
}
```